# Реализация функционала, аналогичного BBCode (preg_replace)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, bbcode

Пытаюсь реализовать нечто, подобное ббкодам (смайлы) из phpbb3.

Пользователь в месте, где должен быть смайл, набивает текст вида `:sm_3:`, нужно впоследствии заменить это на `images/smile/1.gif`, пробую так:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
    $z[] = "/:(sm_$i):/";
};
$message = preg_replace($z, '<img src="{SMILIES_PATH}/$1.gif" / >', $message);
```

но получаю результатом.

```
<img src="images/smile/:sm_3:.gif" / >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не верю.

```
$text=<<<HEREDOC
:sm_1:
:sm_10:
HEREDOC;
for($i=0;$i<50;$i++){$z[]="/:(sm_$i):/";};
echo preg_replace($z,'(img src="{SMILIES_PATH}/$1.gif" / )',    $text);
```

Результат:

```
(img src="{SMILIES_PATH}/sm_1.gif" / )
(img src="{SMILIES_PATH}/sm_10.gif" / )
```

А вообще, красивее так:

```
preg_replace("/:sm_(.+?):/", "текст замены как в вопросе", $message);
```

Без циклов и лишних массивов.

Comment: Спасибо подошло, но нужен именно вариант с массивом, т.к. нужно чтоб именно от 1 до 50 работало...(заметил у себя ошибку :))

Comment: от 1 до 50:  

    preg_replace("/:sm_(0?[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|50):/", "текст замены как в вопросе", $message);

Comment: @ReinRaus ха, очень клево. Тоже думал над этим, но как-то не пришел к выводу.

Answer (score 2):

Первым делом стоит понять, что вы хотите заменять "`:sm_3:`" на "`1`". Сейчас у вас происходит замена "`sm_$i`".

Поэтому:

```
$message=preg_replace("/(?::sm_([0-9]+):)/", '$1', $message);
```

Comment: Чему вы не верите? модер невовремя начал редактировать) результат необходимый я приводил в примере <img src="images/smile/3.gif" / >

Comment: @ToRcH565 обновил пост. И не верю не я :-)

Comment: Чему не вериш то?)

Comment: @ToRcH565 я говорю, что не я не верю :D

Comment: Я не верю в то, что приведены результаты вывода для кода из вопроса. Я просто скопировал себе код из вопроса и он работает именно так, как и задумано.

Comment: Как задумано то он работает, только задумано неверно) скобки не там стояли.... собсно верно подсказали(поняли меня Оо) в отмеченом вопросе)